# dpi & dppx chromium browsers issue

Tags: css, chromium, dpi

Hi guys today i got an issue with css bootstrap, whenever i change the extension of my index from .html to .php this error come out in chromium browsers:

> Consider using 'dppx' units instead of 'dpi', as in CSS 'dpi' means dots-per-CSS-inch, not dots-per-physical-inch, so does not correspond to the actual 'dpi' of a screen. In media query expression: only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), only screen and (min-resolution: 144dpi)

I'm using Bootstrap as CSS framework (bootstrap.min.css & bootstrap.responsive.css)

I'm using no dpi or dppx in my stylesheet that's why i'm confused.

CSS Line that i think the problem is in: `html{font-size:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;}`

and this is my stylesheet (i'm just including css files) :

```
@import url(font-awesome.css);
@import url(bootstrap.min.css);
@import url(bootstrap-responsive.css);
@import url(responsive-slider.css);
@import url(theme.css);
```

I have already tried this in my stylesheet file: `min-size:144dpi;min-size:1.5dppx;` but the problem still in.

please if you need anything just ask me, my html script is too long i can't past it here also i'm sure there is no problem with my Html, just the issue of size unti in chromium browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the problem was in my `include "file.php"` and if anyone else had the same problem i suggest to use

> dpi & dppx unit size in the same stylesheet

goodluck